# Firebase addStateDidChangeListener

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am pretty new to Firebase. I am trying to check if the user is logged in or not, and by referring to the Firebase doc, the recommended way of doing it would be adding a `FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle`.

My code is as follows:

```
  handle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        //here, we add code to see if we are supposed to be loggin or not
        print("hello world")
        if user != nil{
            self.isLogin = true
        }else{
            self.isLogin = false
        }
    })
```

However, after I checked, it seems that `FirAuth.auth()` is a nil and the entire block is not called at all.

Any one knows what is wrong here?

Comment: Solved... What i did was that, i called Firebase.configure() after the view-controllers are loaded. To solve this problem, just place Firebase.configure() as the first line in your app-delegate's didFinishLauching Method

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an improperly set up `Firebase`. Did you follow all the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)? Specifically, did you, in your `AppDelegate`, call `FIRApp.configure()`? Without this configuration call your `FIRAuth` would likely be `nil`.